# I am trying to make side menu in ionic app. But links of side menu not clicking

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-menu

I am trying to make a side menu bar in my app. the side menu is showing. but I can't click those links. When I inspect the page and select an item, it is selected  tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have used this [example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu). This example does not implement click events, to add them:

- In React, use onClick() handler.
- In Angular, use ng-click or bind event (click)

This should be added to every "ion-item" tag in above example.